# Bash - Know if a SSH tunnel has been correctly created

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Here's the situation

I have my computer, named `MY_COMPUTER` a machine named `REMOTE_VM` on which I have a user `remoteuser` that has in `/etc/passwd` the shell `/bin/false`

This user has only one function, doing a SSH tunnel to be able to do after a reverse SSH.

the command I currently use is

```
ssh \
   -nNT \
   -R 42242:127.0.0.1:22 \
   remoteuser@REMOTE_VM
```

I would like this command to be executed in a script and to have a way to get a callback or a way (like putting this ssh command in background and do a periodic check on the existence of a socket file or something like that) to check that the connection has been actually opened and not simply pending connection in the case of a slow network.

Is there such a way with the openssh-client or you have to go with a custom implementation of a ssh client so that you can put your callback whereever you want ?

I would prefer as much as possible a (even dirty) solution with plain openssh-client and bash.

Comment: I think testing for ssh process to be up is all you need

Comment: @Arkadiy but the connection could still be negociating , so you only know that it failed if the process is not up anymore, but that fact the process is up does not assure the connection is established

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command verbosely, capturing the output, then test that the output indicates the session is established? Along the lines of:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
2>"$TMPFILE" ssh -v -nNT -R 42242:127.0.0.1:22 remoteuser@REMOTE_VM &
grep 'debug1: Entering interactive session.' "$TMPFILE"
```

Alternatively, perhaps you could poll the output of `netstat`.

Comment: thanks, actually it looks like a not that dirty solution :)